# How to reuse the same style rule with multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, jss

I want this using jss styling.

```
.a{
height: 20px;
}
.b{
height: 40px;
}
.a,.b{
width: 100px;
}
```

#### Try 1

Make a rule `c` and add the class to both `a` and `b`

```
c: {
width: '100px'
}
```

#### Try 2

Make a object `common` and merge them to both `a` and `b` rule

```
const common = {
   width: '100px',
};

a: {
height: '20px',
...common
}
b: {
height: '40px',
...common
}
```

Is there any better way possible ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about extend plugin (enabled by default)?

https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-extend

```
const styles = {
  buttonColor: {
    background: 'red'
  },
  button: {
    extend: 'buttonColor',
    fontSize: '20px'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A simpler alternative that I feel is easier to parse would be to set the key to be a String by wrapping in quotes:

```js
'.a, .b': {
   width: 100px; 
}
```